# Handling Scala Futures

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, future

I am writing Scala code that checks to see if a zip file is available at a certain location on Amazon S3. If it is, I want to return the path; if it isn't, I want to create it and *then* return the path. The answer is the same either way (assuming no exceptions).

I am using the [Rhinofly play-s3](https://github.com/Rhinofly/play-s3) library for my S3 abstraction, but I don't think that is too relevant. The library does make use of Scala `Future`'s, and that's what matters here. My issue is Scala doesn't like the return type of the method that creates the zip when it isn't available at the start.

Here is my code:

```
def zip(key: String): Future[String] = {
    val zipFileName = key + ".zip"
    val zipFile = bucket get zipFileName //Returns a Future[BucketFile] or S3Exception
    zipFile.map(bucketFile => bucketFile.name).recover {
      case S3Exception(status, code, message, originalXml) => createZip(key)
      case _ => "Who cares for now?"
    }
}
```

Let's assume the happy path and the only exception that is likely to happen is the 404 for no existing zip.

Meanwhile, `createZip(key)` returns a `Future[String]`

The compilation error I get is this:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[String]
 required: String
```

So I want the `zip` method to return `Future[String]`. I thought that the `map` from `zipFile` to `bucketFile.name` returns `Future[String]`, and `createZip` definitely returns `Future[String]`.

So what's the problem? Why is `String` the required return type? How can I rewrite either or both methods to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`recover` will recover `Future` to a default value. In this case, `String`. What you want is `recoverWith` to recover the `Future` with *another* `Future`.

```
def zip(key: String): Future[String] = {
    val zipFileName = key + ".zip"
    val zipFile = bucket get zipFileName //Returns a Future[BucketFile] or S3Exception
    zipFile.map(bucketFile => bucketFile.name).recoverWith {
      case S3Exception(status, code, message, originalXml) => createZip(key)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an asynchronous recovery (i.e., your recover returns a `Future[String]` rather than a `String`. Use `recoverWith`, which lets you use a callback that creates a `Future`. Note that "Who cares for now" would need to be promoted to a `Future` by calling `Future.success("Who cares for now")`, or you could just let the error fall through.